# Expandable height of CardView

Tags: android, cardview

I am working on expand and  collapse of properties on `CardView`.

```
public class SimpleCardView extends CardView {
private int animationDuration;


   public SimpleCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public SimpleCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SimpleCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void expand(){
        final int initialHeight = getHeight();
        final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int targetHeight = (int) (232 * scale + 0.5f);
        final int distance_to_expand = targetHeight - initialHeight;
        Animation animation = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                getLayoutParams().height = (int) (initialHeight +(distance_to_expand*interpolatedTime));
                requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        animationDuration = distance_to_expand;
        animation.setDuration((long)distance_to_expand);
        startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public int getAnimationTime(){
        return animationDuration;
    }

    public void collapse(){}

}
```

This is my screenshot:

[image]

I am setting the constant value for target height.

```
int targetHeight = (int) (232 * scale + 0.5f);
```

Here, `targetHeight` is a expandable height of `CardView`.
Due to this, when the content is too long, only few portion of content is display.

Is there any way to set that height dynamically not a constant value?

Comment: Simple solution bro. Set CardView height wrap_content setYour Title As you do and below TextView Content Visibility should be gone.So when you click for Expand just try to visible the TextView which contains content.

Comment: It's good idea to make view visibility visible/gone. Right now i am doing not that way. So, is there any way to make that target height dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried with :wrap_content

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And you need to remove static height form class `SimpleCardView`.

**OR You need to calculate Height **

For this you need to set Text into `TextView` and then 
calculate height of `TextView` With Below lines and then pass into `SimpleCardView` by making any setter method .

```
TextView textview ;

textveiw.setText("your text");
textview.mesure(0,0);
int height = textview.getMesuredHeight();
```

Comment: Is there any way to put the height dynamically there in `SimpleCardView` class as `WRAP_CONTENT`.